# CakePHP 2.x disable defined rule in model for special field

Tags: php, cakephp

In form I'm using model. In model I have defined validation rules. How I can disable specific rule in form without removing this in model.

I searching for something like that- for solution to set validate false for specific field example:

```
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input(
                        'phone',
                        array('type'       => 'text',
                              'div'        => array('class' => "input-wrap"),
                              'label'      => false,
                              'validate'   => false,
                        )
                    ) ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to alter the validation rules in your controller before you save the form rather than within the View.

For example, if you wanted to remove all validation rules for the `phone` field:-

```
$this->ExampleModel->validator()->remove('phone');
```

If you just want to remove a specific rule from the field you can do that too. For example, if you have a rule named `required` for the `phone` field:-

```
$this->ExampleModel->validator()->remove('phone', 'required');
```

You can read up on this [in the official docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#removing-rules-from-the-set).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also in the controller

```
unset($this->ExampleModel->validate['emailaddress']['unique']);
```